# Removing background not getting fully transparent image in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

As a beginner I am having hard time and sorry for this basic question.
I have bought some vector from ShutterStock and while removing the background layer, I get some black gradient in the edges of the sparkles!

For easier understanding, please see the image below.

How do I get a fully transparent image of the shining frame. [I have the layered vector file of the image]

[image]

Comment: This image seems to have been made to go on a dark background...

Comment: @WELZ I want the transparent frame so that I can set any darkish background programmatically. Isn't possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The objects appear to have been *specifically* created to blend to a dark background.

You won't be able to *easily* alter that. But you *can* alter it.

You will need to select the objects with the dark coloring and adjust the dark color to white or to transparent. *How* one goes about that depends greatly upon *how* the artwork is constructed. It may be a simple matter of adjusting some color fills, or gradient color stops. It is difficult to state.

In some cases internal object construction may prove very intricate and difficult to change.

---

In *this art*.... Many of the objects are merely a gradient fill.

[image]

Select the object and change the gradient so that *both* color stops are the *same* color:

[image]

Then click the color stop that *used* to be dark and set it's *opacity* to 0:

[image]

[image]

Then do the same thing for *all* the other objects with dark in them - replace dark with same color, set that color stop to 0% opacity.

**The reason you need to set the color stops to the same color first** is because if you leave it as the dark color, you are going to get a dark drop-off of the gradient in the middle of it. Sort of a gradient from color to dark and *then* to transparent. Setting the color stops to the same color prevents this drop off when using transparency in a gradient.

Example of the drop-off if you fail to set color stops to the same color:

[image]

Comment: Typically we don't do *specific* file troubleshooting around here, Questions should be broad enough to assist future users as well, not just you. `:)` But okay.... there may be value in explaining for future visitors. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many suggestions to this but I think none of them will get you where you want. If you intend to use this flare somewhere else you don't have to convert into a transparent object. All you need to do is **copy and paste** it in front of the work you intend to **apply the effect** and make sure that **transparency mode** is set to **screen.**

Comment: This *seems* to reference Photoshop layers more than Illustrator artwork. "Screen" doesn't work for PNGs nor printed materials.

Comment: This works completely, kindly revisit.

Comment: "Screen" blending mode does **not** work for CMYK artwork.

Answer (score -2):

Asim, of course it is.

Either those elements are locked, grouped, a clipping path or a compound path.

So unlock everything. Perhaps the frame is a group onto itself and it can be removed or locked leaving everything else to be deleted.

There are two different arrow-selectors ... one selects groups, the other individual paths.