# Extract asset from AI while keeping background transparent with glow effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, transparency, blend-modes

For [this asset](https://stock.adobe.com/images/vector-realistic-set-of-beautiful-muslim-ornamental-lamps-lanterns-hanging-on-chainlets/347155254?prev_url=detail&asset_id=347155254) I need to extract each individual lantern into a separate PNG image while preserving the glow effect. When I downloaded the asset, I thought the lanterns lay on top of the checkered background, which I thought was a background for the purposes of illustrating transparency. However, the background was part of the image, and when I removed it in Ilustrator, I was left with the following:

[image]

If I remove the black ovals, I'm left with lanterns without the glow effect. How can I preserve the glow effect yet remove the black oval? My expectation is to get an individual lantern that would look like the lantern on the checkered background but with a transparent background.

This [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109477/removing-background-not-getting-fully-transparent-image-in-illustrator) has the same problem, but when I follow the steps, I don't get the same behavior. Here's what I see in the gradient panel:

[image]

If I move the gradient stop on the left all the way to the left, I see this:
[image]

If I then change the opacity to 0%, the glow effect is gone:
[image]

Comment: See the duplicate link above. There is no "easy" solution if you want vectors.

Comment: I'm new to AI. I updated my question. Judging from your [solution](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109484/146832) and from the dialog that I see when I click on the oval, it seems like my problem is different.

Comment: You'll need to check the **Gradient Panel**, not the Color Panel. The **Appearance Panel** may also be helpful. Based on your additional screenshot.. the issue is *exactly* the same as the duplicate.

Comment: The Gradient and Color panels are two *separate* panels. You *can* open the Gradient Panel then click an object to see the Gradient that is applied. I don't think Adobe has removed the Gradient Panel.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost at your first step. Firstly, the panel on AI 2024 looks different from what you have. When I move the stop on the left all the way to to the right, I see that the oval is now color of the center of the glow, but I don't see a way to "click the color stop that used to be dark and set it's opacity to 0." But if I go ahead and change the opacity to 0%, the glow effect is gone.

Comment: You don't need to *move* any color stops. Click one, change its color, that's all. I understand if it seems frustrating. But it is only frustrating due to the lack of experience with the tool. Check Adobe help files on the Gradient Panel and brush up on how it functions. The older screenshots from the duplicate don't really matter. All the functionality is the same.

Comment: In short, you aren't actually following the directions properly. Simply *change the dark color stop*, that's all. Click it once and change its settings. *Don't* drag or move *anything*. You should **still** have 2 color stops -- both *set to* the *same color* and one at 100% opacity, the other at 0% opacity.

Comment: Ah, I got it now. You have to double click the gradient stops to get the color. Then you can copy and paste it to the other gradient stop. It's funny how the smallest things are clickable in AI.  Thanks for sticking with me!