# Shine effect lost when attempting to remove black background

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, blend-modes

When I export the [following asset](https://stock.adobe.com/images/crescent-islamic-for-ramadan-kareem-design-element-isolated-silver-glitter-moon-vector-icon-of-crescent-islamic-isolated-luxury-silver-crescent-half-moon-gold-glittering-confetti-particles/269960161) to PNG, I see black circles around where the sparkles are. I used the technique in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109484/146832) to remove the black circles, but I notice the shine effect is gone and replaced with gray instead.

For example, here's the top of the crescent:

[image]

Without the checkered background I have this:

[image]

If I go about removing the black as in the answer above, the sparkle is now gray.

[image]

Comment: You kin of keep asking (basically) the same question which has the same answer -- Check the object, remove blend modes or anything which relies on blend modes for an appearance over a dark background. Chances are there's a blend mode at work there.

Comment: Then this is a different question. I used the same technique in your answer and it doesn't work the same way. Since it requires a different way of solving problem, this requires a different answer.

Comment: It's the same issue essentially.. you need to check the object remove blend modes and possibly adjust for any specific situation. In other words, you need to use some deductive reasoning and find out *why* that particular object is different (Again, most likely a blend mode).

Comment: From what I've seen is that the checkered background masks aides in creating the shine effect. Even in the other questions, I didn't get the same shine effect after removing the checkered background, but the result I got was good enough. In this case, the result is not good.

Comment: If you want to remove the grey in the gradients, make the transparent stop white, not black.  It's really hard to answer questions like this without access to the AI file. It's hard to know exactly how it was constructed.  You will likely have to just try it and see.

Comment: Like i explained to you when you kill the blendmode object stops shining. But yes you can adjust the gradient to mske a transparent mask on top of it. It just wont work on a light background. Because the normal alpha bendingmode dont shine. Sometimes it works sometimes, wont work. Export 2 images

Comment: Exporting two images will be difficult to incorporate in my workflow. This and other assets like this are unusable because it requires so much work to use. The listing photo tricks you.